# Side-by-side comparison is misleading when duplicate space is removed

Tags: bug, review-queues, suggested-edits, diff

This suggested edit queue item:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/32263977

Marks the word "understand" changed here:

[image]

But in reality, a duplicate space after the word "to" was removed:

[image]

This is misleading, since the word "understand" has not been changed at all.